# Can I share an environment variable across different power automate solutions in the same environment?

Tags: power-automate

In Power Automate, we are able to create a solution, and add environment variables for consumption inside flows and apps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/environmentvariables

Environment variables can only be created inside a solution and solutions are created inside an environment. Each environment has its own dataverse where environment variables are stored. This means, I cannot reuse the name of an environment variable from one solution to the next because they conflict inside the dataverse. My first instinct is that now I need to rename my environment variables to contain the solution name as well, i.e. `myenv_solution1_admin-email` or `myenv_solution2_admin-email`. Because I can't use something like `myenv_admin-email` in two different solutions.

This led to the question, **can I share the environment variable across more than one solution?** For example, can I set a global admin email and consume it within flows in any solution in the environment?

Answer (score 1):

To re-use flows and environment variables across multiple solutions in the same environment, you can create a new solution, then use the `Add Existing` option to choose a flow, environment variable or other objects from another solution to be added to the existing solution. This is not a copy of the object, but the actual object. Modifications to the object in one place will propagate to each place it is added.

When removing an item from a solution, you will additionally see the option to remove from the solution or remove from the environment. The latter will delete it from everywhere.

So happy to see this option as it enables us to create a shared functions solution that can be re-used across multiple solutions.

[image]